# Parken oder einparken?

Tags: word-usage, difference, verb, grammatical-case

What is the difference between parken and einparken

Comment: Please use a proper question title next time.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: In Bälde hast Du ja genug Reputation um Fragen zu editieren...

Comment: @userunknown Ich bin ja immer dafür, den OP darauf hinzuweisen als es hinterrücks einfach zu machen...

Comment: Re. The earlier version (pre-edit): If the system asks you to write more, it's better to describe what you found in a dictionary instead of filling it with random text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Einparken* is the process of actually driving your car into the parking space (*ausparken* would be the opposite). For example:

> Ich muss mich konzentrieren während ich einparke!
>   Mein Sohn fährt ganz gut Auto, nur Einparken muss er noch üben.

*Parken* can be the process of parking your car (not just the process of driving it into the parking space, but looking for a free space, driving into the space, locking the car, etc.) as well saying that you parked the car somewhere.

> Bin gleich da, ich muss noch parken!
>   Ich habe am Einkaufszentrum geparkt.

The words can not be used synonymously. While the following two sentences could be used if you want to complain that somebody parked badly, they have slightly different connotations:

> Der hat aber schief eingeparkt!
>   Der hat aber schief geparkt!

The former means that something went wrong when the car was driven into the parking space, the latter means that the car is now parked badly.

Comment: Danke schön :))